# facebook send button blank when site url does not contain filename (index.html)

Tags: facebook, url, button, send

My widget works fine on condition that url of the site contains file name. f.e. It is working with
*www.domain.com/subdomain/path/index.html* and keeps showing blank when address of site is *www.domain.com/subdomain/path/*.

That's kinda weird behavior, i know that there were some issues with facebook's send-box, but i couldn't find one fitting into my bug.

I dynamically change url and make a call to FB.XFBML.parse();
Using such a code for facebook widget then

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : 'appID',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : false,
    xfbml      : true 
});
fbApiInit = true; //init flag
};

(function(d, debug){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
```

}(document, /*debug*/ false));

Please tell me what to do.
The important thing is that i'd rather prefer both of addresses to work, if it's not possible, it would be great to have opportunity to use addres with no filename.ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine now.
I just realized facebook does not allow to use sending no-extension addresses.
I was using
`$('.fbMenu :first-child').attr('href',document.location.toString()).attr('ref','text');`where document location was just a path.
Such a simple code fixed the issue:

`$('.fbMenu :first-child').attr('href',document.location.toString().indexOf('html')==-1?document.location.toString().replace('#','index.html#'):document.location.toString()).attr('ref','text');`